# Return Multiple Values from a function in C#

Tags: return, multiple-return-values

```
public List<string>[],List<string>[] FunctionName()
    {
    }
```

Giving error. I want define multiple List before FunctionName. I dont like out method dont suggest to me please.

```
   public List<string>[],String[] FunctionName()
    {
    }
```

Again gicing error.

Comment: What you want or like is irrelevant if you try to make up features that don't exist. Study the language instead of guessing.

Comment: Ok can you give me any solution for multiple value (multiple List ) ?

Comment: A structure that holds the values.

Comment: Amit could you give me code sample please.